# ¿ Cómo se puede hacer para obligar a mis usuarios a actualizar mi App de android?

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

Tengo una aplicación hecha con `Unity` pero me ha salido **un gran bug** y la tienen algunas personas y no quiero que la utilicen más por lo que me gustaría hacer que cuando abriesen mi App les saliese un cartel diciéndoles que deben actulizarla del google play para poder seguir utilizándola.

Mi app tiene contacto con Google Play Games por lo que tiene acceso a Internet. ¿ Es posible hacer lo antes comentado? He intentado poner un mensaje manualmente pero claro, es un mensaje escrito y ya está, solo texto, pero necesito algo similar que les obligue ir a Google Play si la versión de la App no es la misma que la del Play Store.

Estuve pensando y hay algunas Apps como WhatsApp que si que lo usan, ¿no?

Comment: Si tras la comprobación de que no es la version más reciente, le muestras un pop up informandole, y tras el usuario aceptar, le abres el GooglePlay con el enlace de tu app. Valdria eso ?

Comment: Sí! Eso valdría, es lo que busco. Pero tengo 2 preguntas, cómo se puede comparar una version de Android comparándola con la publicada en Play store y la 2a, ¿Es posible hacer como en ``Android Studio`` bloqueando el touch fuera de ese ``pop up`` para obligarle a ir a Google Play ?

Comment: no se como se hace, es una idea solo. para bloquear el pop up, tiene que ser modal.

Comment: Ah.. es que ya lo había yo redactado en mi enunciado... jeje da igual, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar un servidor externo con una API que te devuelva el último número de versión de la aplicación y comprobarlo contra la que está instalada, si no coinciden se muestra el diálogo con un botón que lleve a la Play Store, tendrías tú que cambiar manualmente el número de versión cuando actualices la app pero puede automatizarse. El único problema es que sólo funcionaría de ahora en adelante y no en las que ya hay publicadas.

Comment: Exacto, eso es, pero sabes cual cómo comprobar la que está instalada para poder comprarla con la que ponga yo manualmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes poner una escena al inicio, Que contenga una variable con un tipo de pass, Supongamos, la pass de la versión mas reciente es: "ASDFG", Y tienes ahora que crear una web, Puede ser hasta blogger o 000webhost, Que solo contenga un texto que sera la ultima clave, Entonces con el metodo de:

```
WWW GetTextWWW = new WWW (Url)
GetTextWWW.text;
yield return GetTextWWW;
```

Puedes averiguar en la web si la clave es la misma de la de app, Si no es asi, Puedes cargar una escena que diga que lo actualize, Si es asi, Solo continua como siempre.

Espero haberme explicado bien, Sino preguntame.

Comment: Asi no es tan complicado, Solo es necesario que cuentes con una url y un host, Pero si no tienes dinero para pagarlo, Puedes simplemente buscar para el dominio (http://www.freenom.com/es/index.html?lang=es) y para el host (https://co.000webhost.com/).

Comment: ok gracias, no tengo tiempo para mirar eso pero para mi proxima app sí que me interesaría, puedes darme un contacto, un correo, para ponerme en contacto contigo?

Comment: Dale, Escribeme si necesitas algo, alejandro.41370@gmail.com

Comment: alejandro, ese es tu correo? estoy con eso ahora mismo